# PHP crypt() function VS. hash() function

Tags: php, hash, sha512

i'm creating a login system in PHP, and i'm experiencing with hashing.

Can someone tell me why if I use hash() with sha512 it generates a string of 128 chars while using crypt() with sha512 it is only 118 chars (but only 103 chars of hash) ?

Example:

```
$password = "password";
$hashed =   crypt($password, '$6$rounds=5000$'.core::genSalt().'$');
$hashed2 =  hash('sha512', $password);

echo "pwd hashed with hash() -> $hashed<br>";
echo "hashed pwd length? ".strlen($hashed);
echo "<br>-----<br>";
echo "pwd hashed with crypt() -> $hashed2<br>";
echo "hashed pwd length? ".strlen($hashed2);
```

and it results in:

```
pwd hashed with crypt() -> $6$rounds=5000$HGWYWN+gVBLsotI5$sxqlewzU4pn4Z0/.5DlX6orE9Mw2W0Z7VJ6Qp8cCQdDqGvCJHqgiG6fYQjI2dSm78ErfXQ8QbMjq1JCVl2Hah0 
hashed pwd length? 118

pwd hashed with hash() -> b109f3bbbc244eb82441917ed06d618b9008dd09b3befd1b5e07394c706a8bb980b1d7785e5976ec049b46df5f1326af5a2ea6d103fd07c95385ffab0cacbc86 
hashed pwd length? 128
```

Thank you

Comment: [password_hash](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) is better than both of them, it generates a salt on it's own

Comment: Hashing functions aren't encryption functions. They aren't designed to reverse the process. Also: Your echoes are reversed. the first line (echo of `$hashed`) is from `crypt()` while `$hashed2` is from `hash()`

Comment: @Arian Yes, if OP's PHP is 5.5 --- If not, then to use the compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/

Comment: @Fred-ii- Definitely agree!

Comment: @Arian i'm using php < 5.5 so I cannot use password_hash()

Comment: YEs, you can, as the previous posters indicated there's a compatibility library that ports it back. That way you use bcrypt and future-proof your code.

Comment: @ccKep Yes i've corrected the error, they was inverted! I know that hashing function are one way, my question is about the length of the string generated by those 2 different functions. Why crypt() generate an hash of 103 chars instead 118 ?

Comment: @user14709 Why would you expect 118 in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hash() uses an hexadecimal representation([a-f0-9]) whereas crypt() seems to use [a-zA-Z0-9./] from what I see.

For the hexadecimal representation, each character holds 4(16 needs 4 binary digits) bits of information, and for the crypt one, each character holds 6(64 needs 6 binary digits).

We know that SHA-512 generates a 512 bit hash, so:

- hash(): 512 / 4 = 128 characters
- crypt(): 512 / 6 = 85,33 ~= 86 characters, which matches with the character length if we strip the crypt mode, rounds, and salt($6$rounds=5000$HGWYWN+gVBLsotI5$). In your example that's "sxqlewzU4pn4Z0/.5DlX6orE9Mw2W0Z7VJ6Qp8cCQdDqGvCJHqgiG6fYQjI2dSm78ErfXQ8QbMjq1JCVl2Hah0"

As an illustration, see what happens when we use 10, 16 or 36 characters to represent a number.

```
$decimalNumber = 123456789;
var_dump(base_convert($decimalNumber, 10, 16), base_convert($decimalNumber, 10, 36));
```